# Functional way to write while loop with mutable variable

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I need to obtain a collection that should be filled with datetime intervals between some input and `LocalDatetime.now`.

Example:

If I would to build a interval based on every 30 minutes, it should be something like `2017-06-12 00:30, 2017-06-12 01:00, 2017-06-12 01:30, 2017-06-12 02:00..and go on`.

I've wrote a code that does my requirement but it looks like Java using Scala syntax - not a functional and cleaner way.

```
  val now = LocalDateTime.now
  val dates = if (interval.toInt > 0) {
    var tempDate = LocalDate.now.atStartOfDay()
    val allDates = scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[String]()
    while (tempDate.isBefore(now)) {
      allDates += tempDate.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"))
      tempDate = tempDate.plusMinutes(interval.toInt)
    }
    allDates
  } else {
    var initialDay = LocalDate.now.minusDays(30)
    val allDates = scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[String]()
    while (initialDay.isBefore(LocalDate.now)) {
      allDates += initialDay.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"))
      initialDay = initialDay.plusDays(1)
    }
    allDates
  }
```

How can I refactor this code to looks like functional style or at least remove that mutable variable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use Scala's `Stream` type to build a lazy stream from the start date in half-hour increments, and then lazily take only as many dates from that which are earlier than the stop date. E.g.:

```
def halfHoursFrom(start: LocalDateTime): Seq[LocalDateTime] =
  Stream
    .iterate(start)(_.plusMinutes(30))
    .takeWhile(_.isBefore(LocalDateTime.now))
```

You will find the documentation for the `Stream` type in the standard library reference. The two notable methods we're using here are:

- `Stream.iterate` (in the `Stream` companion object): builds an infinite stream lazily from a starting value and an increment function
- `Stream#takeWhile` (in the `Stream` class): takes only as many elements from the given stream as match the given predicate (function which tests each element and returns `true`/`false`).

Note that I'm upcasting the return type to `Seq[LocalDateTime]` to hide the implementation details from the caller.

Comment: This is a good answer. I'll just add one tip that tripped me up when I started using Scala: Stream is lazily-evaluated, but it does cache all elements it has computed, so it can use up memory. So this pattern is not *always* applicable when replacing a while loop + mutable var as it can lead to worse memory usage if not collecting results in every iteration. If you don't want to save intermediate results from every iteration `Iterator.iterate` is an equivalent that doesn't use memory in that way.

Comment: @JoeK good point, it's good to carefully note the exact requirements. In this case the request was for a collection of dates as the return value, but after giving it some thought the requestor may find that they can make do with an iterator over the date sequence.